# How to prove $|z|\cdot |w|=|z \cdot w|$ form complex numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, radicals, absolute-value

I am trying to prove $|z|\cdot |w|=|z \cdot w|$

$|z\cdot w|=\sqrt{(ac-bd)^{2}+(ad+bc)^{2}}$
and
$|z|\cdot|w|=\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}\cdot\sqrt{c^{2}+d^{2}}=\sqrt{(a^{2}+b^{2})\cdot(c^{2}+d^{2})}=\sqrt{(a^{2}c^{2}+a^{2}d^{2}+b^{2}c^{2}+b^{2}d^{2})}$

And I'm stuck
Help?

Comment: You should state explicitly what $z$ and $w$ are, and what $a,b,c$ and $d$ are. (That is, introduce quantities before referring to them.)

Comment: Related: [If $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers can we use the proof in $\mathbb{R}$ to demonstrate that $|z w|=|z||w|$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1523974)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, $$(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2=a^2c^2-2abcd+b^2d^2+a^2d^2+2abcd+b^2c^2=$$
$$=a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2=a^2(c^2+d^2)+b^2(c^2+d^2)=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$$

Comment: you just did what i  did backwards how dose this help me prove that $a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2$

Comment: @Lendion Sorry, I thought that this step is obvious. I added something. See now.

Answer (score 4):

We have$$|z.w|=|z|.|w|\iff|z.w|^2=\bigl(|z|.|w|\bigr)^2=|z|^2.|w|^2$$and\begin{align}|z.w|^2&=z.w.\overline{z.w}\\&=z.w.\overline z.\overline w\\&=z.\overline z.w.\overline w\\&=|z|^2.|w|^2.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you know that you can write
$z = r_z e^{i\theta_z}$
where $r_z$ and $\theta_z$ are real.

Comment: ... but actually I like the way shown by José Carlos Santos even better.